# How to convert Xmind file to jpg/pdf?

Tags: pdf, png, converters

How can I convert xmind file to jpg/png/pdf without using Xmind Desktop tool?

I used xmind android app but was able to convert only to markdown, not to png or pdf.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Unfortunately, the particular Xmind file wasn't able to convert to pdf/png. As of now, I'm taking the screenshot of the Xmind file from my android phone.

Comment: I already did, Thanks KJ